# How to copy a folder to another folder within docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm using nginx:alpine docker image.

I try to do the compilation process in Dockerfile, and it generates a folder named dist in the docker container.

At the last step, I try to copy the generated dist folder to /usr/share/nginx/html as instructed in https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

What I have tried is:

```
# Copy dist folder to destination
RUN cp -rf dist /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

But the result is that when I run the image, the nginx displays the default nginx page.

I have also tried to compile before I run docker build, and at the last step of Dockerfile:

```
COPY dist /user/share/nginx/html
```

And this time it works.

Any idea how I can do the compilation in Dockerfile while I can successfully copy the generated dist folder to destination?

Comment: Because docker resets the directory context after every `run` command, you will have to first `cd` into the directory in the same `run` command, or use absolute paths. You may also use `workdir` to set the working directory.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for your tip. But the generated dist folder should be in the original path. As I have not changed the WORKDIR and if I compile locally, the dist folder is also generated in the root project path.

Comment: Can you `exec -it sh` into the running container and inspect the dist directory after building it?

Comment: @Brian Thank you very much! I tried inspecting the /user/share/nginx/html and found that I misused the `cp` command.I should use `dist/.` as `<source>` instead of `dist`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use *two* nginx:alpine images (in the same Dockerfile):

- one for the compilation, where you would generate the dist
- one where you copy the dist from the first image to your actual final image.

This is described as a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It helps me with image size problem, and it's much cleaner.